# Something Like For Loop in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a Resource Dictionary in which I want to have a common DataTemplate for ComboBox.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!--Here I need to use something like For Loop-->
            <TextBlock Text=""></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Now I have created a dependency property of type integer named NoOfColumns. While declaring the comboBox I need to set the NoOfColumns property to automatically generate that number of columns. I want them to `databind`.

**Update as requested by Joe**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbUnder" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupsAndCorrespondingEffects}" 
    IsEditable="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Text="{Binding InputValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextSearch.TextPath="GroupName" 
    Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="3">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:GroupAndCorrespondingEffect}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" Width="250">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHighlighted}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CorrespondingEffect}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Who is owner of that DP? Which columns you want to generate in combobox?

Comment: I am working on an inventory management system. I have all the rights. Some comboboxes have two columns like NameOfTheGroup and CorrespondingEffect. some of them will have 3 columns and some of them will have 1 column. Data is coming from SQL Server.

Comment: No there is nothing like a "loop" in XAML. XAML is a declarative language, not an imperative one. There are no "instructions" and there is no executable XAML code. You're looking for an `ItemsControl`. Please post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: Have you considered a markup extension?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing like `for` in XAML, but `ItemsControl` is very much like `foreach`. Instead of setting an `int` property, make an `ObservableCollection<T>` and add that many objects to it, and then bind the `ItemsControl` to your collection property.

This has the added benefit that each collection item can expose properties to be bound, e.g. if you wanted to display different text in each `TextBlock`, you could put a property on your collection item and bind the `TextBlock` to that property.

Comment: I think you are mis-understanding my question. I want to have a multi-column comboBox and I want to define the columns in a resource dictionary. But the problem is that all the comboBoxes will not have the same no. of columns. I was wondering how to do it.

Comment: I think you'll have to post the code to show how you're doing the columns in your ComboBox (and how you're binding the ComboBoxes' contents, if applicable). An ItemsControl still might do what you want, but it would be harder if the ComboBoxes are databound.